# how to debug javascript on chrome

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, debugging, google-chrome

I have this weird issue that jquery.load sometimes fails on chrome. I'm not gonna bother you guys with the details, I'm just looking for a pointing hand on how can i debug such an issue?

I thought of maybe the firebug could help, but the issue happens only on chrome (even works on IE).

I do something like:

```
$("#contentid").html("Plz wait.");
$("#contentid").load(url);
$("#contentid").show();
```

I get only the "Plz wait" on #contentid, and i can see the url getting called, and check it manually and see it succeeds.

**UPDATE2:**

so i changed the load calls according to suggestions

```
$('#conentid').load(url, function(response, status, xhr){
  alert('Load was performed. url:' + url);
  if (status == "error") 
  {
    alert("text: " + xhr.statusText);
    alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
        alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
  }
  else
  {
      $("#conentid").show(); 
  }
});
```

I get status=='error' when the errors occur.

xhr.statusText: 0

xhr.readyState: 4

xhr.statusText and xhr.responseText are empty

any idea why? what does this mean?

The url works manually. and this error happens only on chrome, and only sometimes

Comment: Have you looked in the Chrome developer tools "Network" tab to make sure the content is there in the HTTP response?

Comment: nice one. they're not there as u suspected. and they do appear on the pages that do work. I can also see them on fiddler on pages that don't work. any clue why?

Comment: Because load is asynchronous -- it hasn't completed yet.  See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone else could have an explanation for this answer, but the problem was:

I had a **base href TAG** (`<base href="http://domain.com/" />`)

There are some references for problems with using jquery + base href out there.
I have no idea why, **but removing this line fixed everything**. thanks for all your help, I learned some web debugging\ajax tips in the process.

Answer (score 4):

Chrome actually has rather nice developer tools.  Click the wrench icon, select developer tools from the menu.

On this particular issue, I'll bet the show is being called before the load completes -- load happens asynchronously.  Set up an [event handler for "on load"](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) on `#contentid` and do the show in that.

**Update**

Actually, there's a [better way to do it](http://api.jquery.com/load/); put your `show` into a callback on the `load` function:

```
$('#conentid').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
  $('#contentid').show();
});
```

**Another Update**

Okay, the ready state of 4 indicates the XmlHTTPRequest completed normally.  Now, there's one ambiguity here: is the xhr.statusText 0 or is it empty?  What results do you see from this code (including the error code) on another browser?

If it's working on firefox, and only working sometimes on Chrome, you may have an actual Chrome bug.

Comment: I'm using the developer tools of course. not sure how to understand why the load() doesn't work with it...

Comment: The asynchronous nature of load (and many other things in JavaScript) is very important for this issue.

Comment: i get the alerts that the content was loaded, but the content isn't loaded, and still the url calls don't show in the Network tool

Comment: @normalppl sounds like an error to me. Check the first callback parameter for an error object

Comment: There's an example of using the error returns at the bottom of the page I linked.  One thing you might try is just loading the URL that you are using from the address bar of a browser, or with cURL: did you get what you expected?

Comment: yes i get what i expect when loading it manually. i can also see the loads on fiddler. but don't see them on chrome's Network dev tool. it works on firefox + IE also, and fails only sometimes here